# Sci kit learn regression random forest regressor implementation

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm having a problem where my scikit learn regression forest trains almost instantly (in a few seconds; I know from experience with this machine it should take about a half hour or more on a dataset of the size I am working on) and then predicts the exact same output for every row of input data.

My current theory is that it has something to with the order of magnitude of the target variables - around 10^-11. I tried multiplying them by 100,000 to see what happened, and it starting running forever and not doing anything until I killed the script.

The code is below:

```
n_estimators = 200
rfr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=n_estimators, verbose = 2, n_jobs = -1)
y_train = df_train[target].values*100000
rfr.fit(X_train, y_train)

rfr.predict(X_train)
```

You're probably wondering why I ran it back on the training data - I was just trying to test if it was actually doing anything, which it isn't.

Thank you for your help!

Edit:

This is the describe() output for the target data. The training data is mostly similar in magnitude:

```
count    4.000000e+04
mean    -1.062353e-11
std      5.990830e-10
min     -1.063333e-08
25%     -2.305633e-10
50%     -6.325584e-12
75%      2.110687e-10
max      1.564848e-08
```

I tried standardizing the data and running the forest; it printed no output but the memory usage keeps creeping up so it must be doing something. Do regression forests take high computer power? I'm using a laptop with an i7 processor and an OK graphics card; I can classify fine.

Comment: What does your training target look like? Try running .describe() on the pandas series.

Comment: Multiple things can go wrong: 1) make sure your X_train has the correct shape. From the documentation: `array X of size [n_samples, n_features]`. 
2) Try to scale and center your data using a [`RobustScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler) or [`StandardScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler). 3) Some old version of joblib has known performance problems. What happens when you try with `n_jobs=1` ?

Comment: I tried the n_jobs fix, and made sure X_train had the right shape. I updated the question with responses to the other suggestions.

Comment: Tell us about x. How wide is X_train? You say that you can classify fine, and one difference between regression and classification RF's in scikit-learn is the default number of features to use. In classifiers, it is sqrt(n_features), but in regressors, it is n_features. So if the width of X_train is, say, 10000, then the regressor would consider 100 times as many features to split on.

Comment: Also, you are troubleshooting at this point. For now, you should use n_estimators=<2 to 5 trees> and maybe limit max_depth, too, until you get it working, then go back to 100's of trees to get a better result.